# Run python tkinter button and push button at the same time on pi

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I have a python program that will display a frame (on a LCD connected to a Raspberry pi) containing a tkinter button at a specified time. When the user presses the tkinter button, a function will be called to turn off a LED and buzzer. I also have a physical push button that calls the same function. The problem is, I cannot run both tkinter and physical button at the same time. Currently with the code below, only the tkinter button, when pressed, is able to call the function. But when i press the push button instead, nothing happens (function is not called; LED and buzzer remains turned on).

My question is how am i able to run both buttons at the same time? So that the user can either press the tkinter button or the push button to turn off the LED and buzzer.

```
....
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def alarm_message(number):
    root.frame = Frame(bg="red")
    root.frame.grid()
    change_colour()
    title_message=Label(root.frame, font = "Arial 150 ",fg='white',bg='black')
    title_message.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=80,pady=170)
    input_state = GPIO.input(18)
    if (number==1):
        title_message.config(text="TAKE YOUR \n MORNING \n MEDICATION ")
        taken_button = Button(root.frame, text="Done",command=lambda:button_pressed(1), font=("Arial", 80),bd=10)  
        taken_button.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=45,pady=100)
        if input_state == False:       
            print('Button pressed: Physical1')
            button_pressed(1)
            time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: I just realised that python needs the if statement to be put in a while loop to continuously check if the button is pressed...

Answer (score 0):

## just change False to True of the last forth line this will definitely work

Comment: You were telling to rassbery pi to check that tkinter button is pressed and pi's button not pressed by using "if input_state == False: it" it should be "if input_state == : True”

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add that i used GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP). So if i use if input_state == : True, the function will be called without pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

## Friend change only the False In your program to True this will work definetly